# How to disable Jupyter's CPU limitation?

Tags: python, jupyter

I wrote a code to run a task in parallel using `multiprocessing` library. When I run this code directly from terminal it is working correctly using the number of cores defined previously.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from minepy import MINE

def mic(pair):

    assert len(pair) == 4 and isinstance(pair, tuple)

    x, y, x_name, y_name = pair

    mine = MINE()

    mine.compute_score(x, y)

    return {(x_name, y_name): mine.mic()}

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1

inputs = [(independent_var.as_matrix(), dependent_var.as_matrix(),
           independent_var.name, dependent_var.name) 
           for i, independent_var in dataset.iteritems()
           for j, dependent_var in dependent_variables.iteritems()
           if len(dependent_var.unique()) > 1]

if len(inputs) > 0:
    with Pool(num_cores) as p:
        results = p.map(func, inputs)
```

But, when I run it via Jupyter on Windows, the cores are consumed correctly during a few seconds. After that, the process is stopped and looked. Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided works fine here.

Maybe you have to provide more data, like the contents of the `inputs` list and/or the definiton of the `func` function, so we can reproduce the problem.

Also check the results of the `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` call you're using - it often doesn't determine correctly the number of cores in many environments.

Comment: I edited my code to help you reproducing my issues. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Did you check `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` for your environment?

Comment: Yes. That worked. My code is running correctly on windows when I call it from CMD, but via Jupyter I am getting this doubt.